# Rubymine - Delayed Job

Tags: rubymine

I was wondering how to add another item to the rubymine debug server startup?
I am looking to start the delayed job worker with the server debug startup instead of opening it in parallel in command line?

In production this problem is solved using foreman ofcourse.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Before launch** options in the Run configuration:

[image]

Comment: Are you using Rubymine 5? I dont have that option... I only have the option to run a rake task (and that hangs my server from loading)

Comment: Yes, RubyMine 5.0, all default plug-in enabled, [Rails Run/Debug configuration](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/9682/20130213004329.png). Your rake task should probably fork the process so that its execution completes and the process continues to run detached.

Comment: I guess thats the reason... I have rubymine 4.54. I'll upgrade soon!